# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, jtable, setvalue

I have multiple `JSpinner` which have items 1-10 ,  and one `JTable`. When the `JSpinner` is clicked, the value will be added to `JTable`. I want to get the row number so I can use it at `setValueAt`. But I get error when the `JSpinner` clicked more than once times.

**Code**

```
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {  // when JSpinner clicked
        int quantity = (int) ((JSpinner) e.getSource()).getValue();
        int rows = table.getRowCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; i++) {
            if (numspinner[i] == e.getSource()) {
                if (quantity == 1) {
                    System.out.println("Row"+rows);
                    dtm.addRow(new Object[] { foodLabel[i].getText(), quantity, price[i] * quantity });
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Row"+rows);
                    dtm.setValueAt(quantity, rows, 3); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I clicked the same JSpinner more then once and get this output

```
Row1
Row2

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 >= 2
        at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.setValueAt(Unknown Source)
        at gui.FoodOrdering.stateChanged(FoodOrdering.java:250)
        at javax.swing.JSpinner.fireStateChanged(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JSpinner$ModelListener.stateChanged(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractSpinnerModel.fireStateChanged(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel.setValue(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JSpinner.setValue(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicSpinnerUI$ArrowButtonHandler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I have move some code and here the latest

```
  public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            int quantity = (int) ((JSpinner) e.getSource()).getValue();
            int rows = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; i++) {
                if (numspinner[i] == e.getSource()) {
                    if (quantity == 1) {
                        System.out.println("Row"+rows);
                        rows = table.getRowCount();
                        dtm.addRow(new Object[] { foodLabel[i].getText(), quantity, price[i] * quantity });
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(" The Row"+rows);
                        dtm.setValueAt(quantity, rows, 1); // obj,column,row
                    }
                }
            }   
    }
```

If the quantity is 1, it adds row as expected. When click the same JSpinner again, it always display 0!!!

Comment: With zero based indices, like the `JTable`/`TableModel`, `getRowCoun()` return the number of rows, that is larger than the last row's index. EG if you have 3 rows, they are indexed as 0; 1; 2. There is no index 3...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto I thought the 2 is column ?

Comment: The stacktrace shows, that the `setValueAt()` method is called, and it is calling `Vector.elementAt()`, and this throws the exception. The `setValueAt()` method is called with column value of constant 3...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto How can I solve that ? I click the same JSpinner twice, and I get out Row 1 , Row 2, then crashed

Comment: It seems like at your first click, it adds the new row, but at your second click it tries to modify the cell at row index 2..

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto pulling my hair out...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto No idea why it will display Row2 in second times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your setup is incorrect.

You use quantity to "guess" the index. If quantity becomes `1`, you add a new row to the table, if it is not `1`, then you try to modify a row in the table. This has a few faults:

- If there are more than one spinner, click each, and finally click any one of them a second time, which row should be modified?
- If you click on a spinner twice, and then click on its `-` button to decrease and it becomes `1` once again, a new row would be added...

To address the above problems, there are a few options.
The most trivial one would be to implement your own `TableModel` not based on `DefaultTableModel`...
Another approach could be adding a column to your existing `DefaultTableModel` to be used for searching, and making it invisible. This column could be EG the `JSpinner` instance.

So try something like this:

```
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
   final int quantity = (int) ((JSpinner) e.getSource()).getValue();
   final int rows = table.getRowCount();
   for (int row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
      // look for the row that has the JSpinner in its last column
      if (dtm.getValueAt(row, 3) == e.getSource()) {
         // log out something
         System.out.println("Modifying row " + row);
         // modifying the value in the model
         dtm.setValueAt(quantity, row, 1); // obj, row, column
         return;
      }
   }
   // there was no row with this JSpinner, so we have to add it
   for (int i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; i++) {
      // looking for the "clicked" JSpinner
      if (numspinner[i] == e.getSource()) {
         // log out something
         System.out.println("Adding row " + rows);
         // adding a new row to the model
         dtm.addRow(new Object[] { foodLabel[i].getText(), quantity, price[i] * quantity, numspinner[i] });
         return;
      }
   }   
}
```

Comment: It display _Adding row_